# How can I allow precision loss over pyspark jdbc from oracle?

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, pyspark

I am attempting to move a very large Oracle table which contains 300+ columns and 10,000,000+ records using `pyspark 3.0.1` over [DataFrameReader.jdbc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=jdbc#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.jdbc). I get the error message:

`java.lang.ArithmeticException: Decimal precision 136 exceeds max precision 38`

- I can't say which record, or even which column for that matter, is causing this error.
- Furthermore, I plan to repeat this process with many tables and need to automate handling this error.
- I do not have the permissions to change any data in the source database (read-only).
- Decimal precision of 136 is not necessary for my use cases.
- **If there is a way to actually allow precision of 136, I would also be ok with that solution.**

Everything I find online about this issue is regarding others wanting to preserve their decimal precision (not reduce it). I have tried adding the following to my SparkSession config:

`spark.sql.decimalOperations.allowPrecisionLoss=true`

But I still get the same error.

Update:

I was able to get the data to load, then I cast the decimal columns to float.

```
raw_data = self._get_spark().read.jdbc(self._url, self._table, **self._load_args)
decimal_cols = []
for column in raw_data.columns:
    if isinstance(raw_data.schema[column].dataType, DecimalType):
        decimal_cols.append(column)

    for col_name in decimal_cols:
        raw_data = raw_data.withColumn(col_name, col(col_name).cast('float'))
```

Next, I add a new column and make it a float as well. Printing data.schema shows that none of my datatypes in the dataframe is DecimalType. Finally, whenever I go to write back over jdbc I get the same error message.

```
data.write.jdbc(self._url, self._table, **self._save_args)
```

`java.lang.ArithmeticException: Decimal precision 136 exceeds max precision 38`

Comment: can you specify a schema with float type columns while reading the table?

Comment: @mck not sure how that would work using the available params on the jdbc module

Comment: in the `table` argument you can specify something like `select cast(col_a as float), cast(col_b as float) from table`

Comment: Could you try to get the schema from that Oracle table in Spark using dtypes? Just use df.dtypes and search the column that is causing that problem and then try to load that table with a custom schema, something like that: schema = "your_col Decimal(38,10)" and set  .option("customSchema", schema) in your spark.read.format("jdbc"). You could extract all dtypes from the tables and automate the schema creation. Would that solve your problem?

Comment: @KevinBarranco it sounds like this would work except in your example you use type Decimal(38,10) which I think is what is currently being inferred correct? Wouldn't I need to use float somehow as suggested by @mck?

Comment: @KevinBarranco actually I'm not sure how to access spark dtypes before the df has been loaded. Right now I'm thinking I need to use ```sqlalchemy``` to search Oracle type NUMBER columns and then use @mck's ```cast``` solution.

Comment: I see, so right when you run the spark.read the ArithmeticException occurs? Or only when you execute a action like show, count? If that is not working, then the cast to float that @mck suggested is the best option. You could provide the customSchema option with the schema "col1 float, col2 float" and so on. That way, you can avoid creating a custom query for every table you have to load.